# tensorflow conditions: check if the values inside the tensor is zero or greater

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have the following tensor:

```
pmi=tf.constant([[1.5,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,2.9],[1.001,5,1]])
```

I want to have a corresponding tensor Fpmi (or a scaler) such that when the element inside the PMI tensor greater than 0 the element in the Fpmi should be one and when the element in the pmi=0 the element in the Fpmi =0.0005.

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where), with which you can conditionally return elements from two constant tensors:

```
a = tf.constant(1, shape=pmi.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(0.0005, shape=pmi.shape, dtype=tf.float32)

tf.where(tf.greater(pmi, 0), a, b).eval()

#array([[  1.00000000e+00,   5.00000024e-04,   5.00000024e-04],
#       [  5.00000024e-04,   5.00000024e-04,   1.00000000e+00],
#       [  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original values if they are not greater than the threshold, replace the second parameter of tf.where with the original data.

```
data = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 2))

threshold = 0.4
fill_value_if_bigger = tf.constant(0.5, shape=data.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
replaced = tf.where(tf.greater(data, threshold), fill_value_if_bigger, data).numpy()
```